# EKS Node Group creation error via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to provision EKS with node group via terraform

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks-node-group" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks-cluster.name
  instance_types = var.instance_types
  node_group_name = "tf-name"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks-node-group.arn
  subnet_ids      = var.subnet_ids
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 1
    min_size     = 1
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-worker-node-policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-cni-policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-registry-read-only-policy
  ]
}
```

I am trying to provision it using private subnet.

However I am getting an error of

> One or more Amazon EC2 Subnets of [] for node group  does not
> automatically assign public IP addresses to instances launched into
> it. If you want your instances to be assigned a public IP address,
> then you need to enable auto-assign public IP address for the subnet.
> See IP addressing in VPC guide:

What do I need to do?

Comment: Is that an error or a warning?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `"terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"` to define the VPC configuration.

By default, the VPC will not assign public IP. Please update this attribute to `true`.

```bash
map_public_ip_on_launch = true
```

Reference:

- [Github discussion](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/13071)
- [Official Documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest#input_map_public_ip_on_launch)

Answer (score -1):

You can find your answer from AWS Documentation : [Managed node groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html)

"Amazon EKS managed node groups can be launched in both public and private subnets. If you launch a managed node group in a public subnet on or after April 22, 2020, the subnet must have MapPublicIpOnLaunch set to true for the instances to successfully join a cluster. If the public subnet was created using eksctl or the Amazon EKS vended AWS CloudFormation templates on or after March 26, 2020, then this setting is already set to true. If the public subnets were created before March 26, 2020, you must change the setting manually. For more information, see Modifying the public IPv4 addressing attribute for your subnet."